# Bad neighbours: amscd and mtpro2

Tags: amsmath, mtpro

The following code shows how `amscd` and `mtpro2` do not play well together with the `subscriptcorrection` option enabled:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[subscriptcorrection]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amscd}

\begin{document}

\[
 \begin{CD}
     H_{R}(U) @>d >> B
 \end{CD}
\]

\end{document}
```

This halts with the error

```
! Package amscd Error: Invalid use of @.
```

It can be sort of *corrected* with

```
 \disablesubscriptcorrection
```

before the diagram, but the results are less than optimal.

I expect that the problem has to do with catcode values of _ like in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393365/bad-interaction-between-neighbor-packages-xy-polyglossia-biblatex-mtpro2), but nonetheless the conflict is there. The question is:

Who is at fault here? `amscd` or `mtpro2`? Or even LaTeX for now allowing interaction between packages.

Comment: An unfortunate combination of circumstances.

Comment: @Sebastiano That's indeed the problem to solve.

Comment: @egreg Sorry I thought it was just the problem of the position of `@` or TeX primitive syntax `$$...$$`. I have deleted my previous comment for your edit = my comment. Thank you always very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem clearly is in the subscript: `mtpro2` makes `_` math active and its expansion throws in a redefinition of the scratch macro `\next`, which `CD` expects not to change.

*Whose fault is it?* This question has no answer, I'm afraid. Possibly the most culpable is `CD`, where `\next` is used in a dubious way, assuming its meaning will not change for a long span of time. However, it's quite late for changing it.

A simple workaround would be protecting the entry by braces.

```
\begin{CD}
  {H_{R}(U)} @>d >> B
\end{CD}
```

The issue can also be fixed on the `mtpro2` side using a different command name than `\next` in a crucial macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection,lite]{mtpro2}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`~=`_
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\futurelet\next@@@\s@@b}
\def\s@@b{\ifcat\relax\noexpand\next@@@\expandafter\sb\else
 \expandafter\s@@b@\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
 \begin{CD}
     H_{A}(U) @>d >> B
 \end{CD}
\]
\[
\disablesubscriptcorrection
 \begin{CD}
     H_{A}(U) @>d >> B
 \end{CD}
\]

\end{document}
```

I added the version with `\disablesubscriptcorrection` to show that the correction is indeed done as expected in the first diagram.

[image]

---

There are much better packages for diagrams, which won't suffer from this problem.

Just by way of example, here's a diagram impossible to draw with `CD`; it sports the subscript correction and also arrow matching those of `mtpro2`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection,lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
H_{A}(U) \arrow[r,"d"] \arrow[dr,"\varphi"] &
B \arrow[d]
\\
& C
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have two questions, the first one of them is -- it seems that the problem is with LaTeX then, for now allowing a space where conflicting definitions would trespass on one another?

Comment: the other being: What are the `better packages` for diagrams? As far as I know both `xymatrix`  and `disgrams` suffer from the same issues...

Comment: @PauloNey not sure what you mean by the problem is with  latex. TeX is a macro expansion language and there is no namespacing or encapsulation of internal implementation of commands, All definitions have potential conflict with all other definitions, it is only by social contract of packages using "hopefully unique" names like `\mypackage@next` that such conflicts can be avoided.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that is exactly what I meant, there is no namespacing, but latex could enforce a naming convention for the macros -- in order to make the packages better neighbours.

Comment: @PauloNey how can it enforce it? it's recommended for latex2e and made more or less essential for natural use in expl3/latex but even in expl3 code there is virtually no way to enforce it. latex is written in tex it can not change the rules of that language.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Of course one cannot sandbox the execution of the code, but I can see two levels for the enforcement. One would be for a deposit on CTAN, or at least to receive a badge of "Good Neighbour" on CTAN. It would be nice to have such classification -- in this case AMSCD and MTproII would branded as bad-neigbours. I also think that even some automated testing of package mixes would be possible. Finally I need to be convinced that latex itself cannot do the re-labeling necessary at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead I have used `\xymatrix` (http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyguide.pdf)  to draw the same figure of best user @egreg.

You can observe that it works well also with `mtpro2` v. `lite` obtaining the same result. Since the labels were not placed in the center of each arrows I set up an arbitrary spacing (for example `\ar[r]^(.65){d}` in particular `(.65)`)  that after some compilations gave me the figure that I wanted.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection,lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage[all]{xy}


\begin{document}
\xymatrix @R=2pc@C=2pc{ H_{A}(U) \ar[r]^(.65){d} \ar[dr]^(.55){\varphi}&  B \ar[d]\\
 & C
}
\end{document}
```